# Using Merge with in_memory workspace and ArcPy in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, merge, error-000732, in-memory

I am using ArcMap 10.4.

I am attempting to merge three tables, all within the in_memory workspace. The merge appears to work fine, but when I try to call the merged table, it cannot be found. I have isolated the issues to this very basic code:

```
pt = 'eo_sourcept'
ln = 'eo_sourceln'
py = 'eo_sourcepy'

point = arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(pt, "in_memory", "point")
line = arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(ln, "in_memory", "line")
poly = arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(py, "in_memory", "poly")

sourceFeatures = arcpy.Merge_management([point, line, poly], os.path.join("in_memory", "sourceFeatures"))

arcpy.MakeTableView_management(sourceFeatures, "sourceView")
```

I get the error:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset in_memory\sourceFeatures does not exist or is not supported
```

I am getting this error for any tool I try to run while using the in_memory merged dataset. If I set the path to a local/permanent drive, the merged table can successfully be called.

The merge tool is the only tool that I have come across that I have had problems with the in_memory output not being able to be found. Any ideas?

Comment: Working for me merging two tables from disk and then get count / make table view. What is `arcpy.Exists('in_memory/sourceFeatures')` ?

Comment: The result of arcpy.Exists('in_memory/sourceFeatures') is False.  I'm baffled. I can replace with another tool, and it works fine, or I can replace with another local path, and it works fine.

Comment: What happens if you hard code the in_mem fc?  `sourceFeatures = arcpy.Merge_management([point, line, poly], r"in_memory\sourceFeatures")`

Comment: Or set your `arcpy.env.workspace = "in_memory"` and then just output `sourceFeatures`

Comment: I have tried hard coding the in_mem fc and setting the environmental workspace with the same results.

Comment: I have copy/pasted your code above, substituting my own point/line/poly datasets, and it ran with no issues.  Are you running this from within ArcMap or is it a stand-alone tool?  If you run it line-by-line in the Python window in ArcMap, does it add the new in_memory layers into your Table of Contents for each line?

Comment: I am currently running this within ArcMap.  If I run it line-by-line in the Python window in ArcMap, it adds the point, line, and poly, tables to the Table of Contents, but does not add the sourceFeatures table (the product of the merge) and does not throw an error.

Answer (score -2):

As of June 2023 with ArcPy library associated with ArcGIS Pro 3.1, there are still bugs with using in_memory layers and the arcpy.Merge_management tool. For me, the strangeness includes truncating all of my TEXT field attribute values to 1 character. This does not happen when in_memory layers are first copied to disk, then merged.

Comment: The question is about using ArcMap.  Your answer is about using ArcGIS Pro.  Where is one or more of these "bugs" recorded?

Comment: I believe the question and issue is not really about ArcMap, since arcpy libraries cannot be scripted within the ArcMap gui. The issue is the arcpy library and geoprocessing that comes with ArcMap, but is used independently in scripts. Thats the only way to *choose* to use in_memory processing feature classes  as sources of arcpy’s merge tool. 

My point is, and still relevant, that even after the changes and improvements to the Arcpy library from ArcMap based on Python 2.7, to the arcpy library based on python 3.x, the merge function continues to have bugs when using in_memory sources.

Comment: I should have been clearer and said that the question is about using the ArcPy installed with ArcMap and your answer is about using the ArcPy installed with ArcGIS Pro. In any event where is one or more of these "bugs" recorded?  If you can see one reproducibly then that would be a useful question for this site.